# Get-Service unable to open service control manager

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a function that checks for the status of a particular service on a remote machine. When I try to get the service status using `Get-Service -ComputerName RemoteServer`, I get following error.

> Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'RemoteServer'. This operation might require other privileges.

This error only happens in one or two servers, but when I use `Get-WmiObject -class win32_service -ComputerName RemoteServer` I get the service information.

Could you please help identifying the problem in here? I am having administrator privileges on the remote machine and I am running the script from PowerShell ISE as administrator.

Comment: I've only seen this in relation to SQL before, but it turned out to be an issue where the server wasn't properly talking back to the DC, only seemed to cause an issue in this scenario though. check that the permissions are correct and then review the event log on the remote machine?

Comment: Thank you @ConnorLSW for looking into the issue. The error was caused by disabled 'server' service on the remote service.

Answer (score 0):

On investigation, we found that port 445 was in NOT_LISTENING state. The issue was caused by disabled server service. Issue resolved after enabling and starting the service.

Following [link](https://superuser.com/a/1001889/742738) was useful in resolving the issue

Thank you all for looking into this error and suggesting edits on the question. This was my first question in stack overflow and I am loving this experience.