# PowerShell Get-Service | Stop-Service in Azure DevOps no longer working after 1 successful run

Tags: azure, azure-devops

PowerShell 5.1
Azure DevOps 2020 1.1

I successfully ran the following script once in Azure DevOps, then after that I get

> Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer
> 'ABC123'. This operation might require other  privileges.

Why all of a sudden after one good run, I cannot stop the service again? smh

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - powershell: |           
        $teamDev = '$(Library.Variable)'
        $computers = @()
        $computers += $teamDev

        $results = Get-Service -ComputerName $computers 
        $results | Stop-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem, it seems this problem is related to the service is disable.

You could try to use the if condition to check the service and then to use the Get-Service.

Similar problem, you could refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782660/get-service-unable-to-open-service-control-manager).